# Joomla 3 Unknown column 'newTags'

Tags: joomla, tags, updatemodel

While updating a record in the database, I get an error "unknown column 'newTags'".

The update is a classic save/update procedure in Joomlas Backend. Before, I select an item in the listview for editing, afterwards I save the item in the edit view. The ony difference to all my other models/tables is that this one has a column called 'tags'.

While updating the record, the system is trying to update all columns with the right values. But at the end, the system puts a new column called 'newTags' to the update statement and tries to insert the same values like in my 'tags'column. Here, the update procedure fails with the error "unknown column 'newTags'". This would be right, because there is no column 'newTags'.

What is going on here?

Update to this post:
Joomla checks your data array before it will bind the array for saving. The admin legacy model checks, if there is a column called 'tags' and when there is a column called 'tags' it adds the column 'newTags' to the $table and fills it with the values of the 'tags' column. You can find it in /libraries/legacy/model/admin on line 1059:

```
if ((!empty($data['tags']) && $data['tags'][0] != ''))
        {
            $table->newTags = $data['tags'];
        }
```

So why does Joomla add a new column 'newTags' to the Tableitem, while this will afterwards result in an error, because it is not possible to save this new 'virtual' column?

Comment: Let me guess, Joomla 3.1?

Comment: Joomla Version 3.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following directory : "administrator\components\com_componentname", is there a directory named "tables", open it.

Find the file that is associated with the table (normally this is the same name).

Open the php file and check If there's a property named "newTags" instead of "tags".

Comment: What's the component name ? I think that you will need to debug the model of this component.

Comment: it is a custom component. I already tried to debug this problem. But I cannot find, where the system is going to add a new column itself while updating a existing database record. It seems there was a change going on with Joomla 3.1 and its new tags feature.

Comment: You need to find the part of the model who manage the database records. Find the method that insert record in database. If you don't find any issue, You've a last solution : shortcut the insert method with your own recording script, check the JDatabase class, there's a method that give you the possibility to insert content easily. http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: the question is, what is the problem in case of having a column named "tags" since Joomla 3.1. This is why the problem arises. Of yourse I can work around with custom insert statements. Rather I would like to know, what are the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

In your form definition if you have a tag field like below you will see this error.

```
<field 
  name="tags" 
  type="tag"
  labelclass="control-label"
  label="JTAG" 
  description="JTAG_DESC"
  class="inputbox span12 small"
  custom="deny"
  multiple="false"
  mode="nested"
/>
```

The problem is multiple="false" which causes $table->newTags to be set in /libraries/model/legacy/admin.php at line 1059:

```
if ((!empty($data['tags']) && $data['tags'][0] != ''))
{
    $table->newTags = $data['tags'];
}
```

Solution: In the field definition set multiple="true" so $data['tags'] gets passed as an array and so the field is not bound directly or cannot be interpreted as a column. This resolves the problem but doesn't help if you want to limit the choice to one tag.